# APA (sixth edition) citation for the Fourth Assessment Report

Tags: technical-writing, citations

I'm trying to cite a source from the IPCC Fourth Assessment Report: http://www.ipcc.ch/publications_and_data/publications_and_data_reports.shtml

I'm fairly new to APA in general and I'm struggling to come up with the proper format for this. Even using citation generators, I'm not sure where to find all the authors or even the type of citation to use (http://citationmachine.net/index2.php?start=&reqstyleid=0&stylebox=2 -- is it "government", "compiled", "academic", "reference", etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authored report, from a nongovernmental organization. APA 6th edition Section 7.02 - #33.

Author (year). *Article Title* (Research Report No. if there is a number). Retrieved from Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change (IPCC) website: http://www.ipcc.ch/publications_and_data/publications_and_data_reports.shtml

Note, I did not know which report you are referring to.  You won't want to use the citation to the general website, you want the exact page.

Comment: +1 Perfect, to the point answer.  There seems to be no need to cite the individual authors as feared in the OP.

Comment: Actually, yes, Where it says Author, above, if you have authors it would be something like:   Washington, George & Lincoln, Abraham (2011). If there is a corporate or institutional author, it would be something like:   American Psychological Association, Task Force on Web Semantics (2011). and then the rest of the information. One more, a brief, would be:  Employee Benefit Research Institute. (2011, February). and then the rest of the information. Make sense? Let me know if not.

Comment: 'Employee Benefit ...' is the kind I had meant. Thanks for clarifying 'institutional authors', which I had overlooked mentioning.